# How to close any open activity from other activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

Hi I want to finish previously opened activity on current activity . There is any way to doing this . If possible please suggest me usable link or examples.

Comment: Why do you need to do it, can you describe it? Maybe you need something else than closing an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Broadcast.
Example:
In your current activity

```
Intent i = new Intent("Some action");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

In your previous activity

```
YourBroadcastReceiver receiver = new YourBroadcastReceiver();
registerReciver(receiver, new IntentFilter("Some action"));
```

You can invoke finish method in the YourBroadcastReceiver's onReceive method.

Answer (score 0):

When your previous activity has been completely covered by your next Activity, then `YourPrevoiusActivity::onStop()` will be called and you can do whatever you need from that `onStop`

Comment: I think Dawid's answer above has more details. I wonder though why do you want finish() ? You can kill/release whatever you want in onStop() and Android will destroy your activity when he needs to. Even you can pause/resume whatever you want in onPause()/onResume()

Answer (score 0):

If your first activity will not be using, you can call onStop() like this:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    this.finish();
}
```